# Tomcat 9 ant deployment issue with config option. Why?

Tags: tomcat, ant, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy an war file on tomcat using ant, having config option on the deploy task for context path *.xml file. However, the value have not been taken into consideration while the deploy task being executed.

Below is my code and context config file:

```
<deploy url="http://localhost/manager/text" username="${user}" password="${password}" war="${warfile}" update="true" path="/rmd" config="${contextConfig}"/>
```

context.xml

```
<Context path="/rmd/app" docBase="rmd"/>
```

The application is accessible using the url - `http://localhost/rmd` but I am expecting it to be accessible as `http://localhost/app/rmd`.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Change path attribute from `/rmd` to `/app/rmd`.

Updated `<deploy>` tag :

```
<deploy url="http://localhost/manager/text" username="${user}" password="${password}" war="${warfile}" update="true" path="/app/rmd" config="${contextConfig}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this, however application page is not loading, just a blank page is coming up. Everything works fine if i do a manual deployment and having an context docbase entry on server.xml. Only through ant am facing the issue.